# Phpbrew on ubuntu – how to change version?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, version, php

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "precise", php 5.3.10 (from apt-get), fresh phpbrew 1.17.2, and php 5.4.35 installed with phpbrew. But it works only for cli.

```
$ php -v # 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11
$ phpbrew install 5.4.35 +default +fpm
$ phpbrew switch 5.4.35
$ nginx -s reload
$ service php5-fpm restart
$ php -v // PHP 5.4.35
$ curl -IL example.com | grep Powered # still 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 ! Why?
```

Than i've tried new fpm from brew bind into another pid `/var/run/php54-fpm.pid` and reconfigure some servers for `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php54-fpm.pid;`.
`$ phpbrew fpm start` works correclty, but example page with `phpinfo();` returns 5.3 version.

How to *really* switch php version in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This Issue is explained here:

https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/226

Basically you have to link the php *.so files within your apache config by hand.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Someone has tested this? I've already make full upgrade to 5.4 and now can't test solution.