# PhpStorm Installation issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, phpstorm, java

I am back here again with one more issue that I am having installing PhpStorm on my Ubuntu 14.04. To do so I followed the following steps:

**Step 1.** `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*` which gave me a long list mostly saying **Package  is not installed, so not removed**. A few examples:

> Package 'openjdk-7-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'openjdk-7-doc' is not installed, so not removed
>   ...
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

**Step 2:** `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` which ended up saying this:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    oracle-java7-set-default : Depends: oracle-java7-installer but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**Step 3:** Despite those error messages popped up I went ahead and ran `sudo apt-get update` which executed OK.

**Step 4:** Tried to run `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` which again popped up a lot of negative remarks!

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   oracle-java7-installer : Depends: java-common (>= 0.24) but it is not installable
>   Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not installable
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I did not go further with rest of the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default`
`wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-7.1.3.tar.gz`
`tar -xvf PhpStorm-7.1.3.tar.gz`
`cd PhpStorm-133.982/bin`
`./phpstorm.sh`

I have no idea what is going wrong! Somebody please help this absolute newbie to install it.

On another note, if PhpStorm fails to install somehow on my PC, please suggest me a good software which runs on Ubuntu with an inbuilt `SASS` compiler so that I do not have to run a command every time from terminal? And it would be even better if that software I can get for free! PhpStorm is only a 30-day trial.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you must choose a proper website to ask about Linux and Ubuntu questions. Please visit sister website http://askubuntu.com for any questions about Linux and Ubuntu

Comment: Updating Ubuntu is not an option? 16.04 is released. Besides: I don't know why you would not want to use OpenJDK, it works perfectly well with PhpStorm. And IF you insist on using Oracle Java, at least use version 8. The version 7 installer hasn't been updated for the past 3-4 security issues.

Comment: Why?!! There are many questions residing related to Ubuntu on Stack overflow. So why this question is downvoted and closed? An example is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241321/phpbrew-on-ubuntu-how-to-change-version and it is not downvoted yet!

Comment: @Ext3h - thanks so much for your reply. How can I restore / reinstall OpenJdk? Updating to 16.04 is not an option for me. The application I am going to work on is built in 5.3.0 and 16.04 does not support 5.3 series (if I am not wrong)

Answer (score 3):

Strange, I'm using PhpStarm on Ubuntu 14.04 and ant works fine. IntelliJ IDEs are really great.

I have these Java from the same repo you are using.

- java-common-0.51
- java-wrappers-0.1.27
- oracle-java7-installer-7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1

Let's try to purge all the Java packages from you system and then install the Oracle Java again.

Use `dpkg -l | grep java` to discover all the installed java-related packages.

Then, use `apt-get purge` on all of them.

Skip the `javascipt` packages of course.

Then, try to install `oracle-java7-installer` again. I hope it will be installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question and added a screen shot of `dpkg -l | grep java` output.

Comment: Thanks again for your idea. I reinstalled java JDK using `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` and then ran `wget http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2016.1.tar.gz`, `tar -xvf PhpStorm-2016.1.tar.gz`, 
`cd PhpStorm-145.258.2/bin`, `./phpstorm.sh` one by one which finally  installed PhpStrom successfully :)

Answer (score 0):

To install Phpstorm in Ubuntu just follow these steps

1.Run `sudo apt install snapd`

2.Then `sudo snap install phpstorm --classic`

3.Then type `phpstorm` in shell and press enter to launch Phpstorm

Read more about these [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=linux-version)